# Radio button values in form not passing to action (mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post using a form consisting of two groups of two radio buttons, used for sorting:  `Name/Rating` and `Asc/Desc`  Using them, I want to send 2 boolean values to an action but it's not working. It is posting, but the values aren't getting passed, the default values are always passed. What's the problem here?

View with the radio groups:

```
<form action="../Restaurant/RestaurantsSort" method="post" class="btn-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">

     // First radio group:  Name / Rating
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
            <input type="radio" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" value=1 checked> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></span>Name
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" value=0> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>Rating
        </label>
    </div>

     // Second radio group:  Asc / Desc
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
            <input type="radio" name="asc" id="asc" autocomplete="off" value=1 checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> Asc
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="asc" id="asc" autocomplete="off" value=0><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span> Desc
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="list" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Sort" style="margin-top: 5px;"/>

</form>
```

Action being called:

```
// name is always true, asc is always true
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RestaurantsSort(bool name = true, bool asc = true)
{
    List<Restaurant> r = new List<Restaurant>();
    switch (name)
    {
        case true:
            switch (asc)
            {
                case true:
                    r = Restaurant.GetRestaurants("restaurants", "sortby", "name", "asc");
                    break;
                case false:
                    r = Restaurant.GetRestaurants("restaurants", "sortby", "name", "desc");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case false:
            switch (asc)
            {
                case true:
                    r = Restaurant.GetRestaurants("restaurants", "sortby", "rating", "asc");
                    break;
                case false:
                    r = Restaurant.GetRestaurants("restaurants", "sortby", "rating", "desc");
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    TempData["restaurants"] = r;
    return RedirectToAction("Restaurants");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your radio buttons have values `0` and `1`. You cannot bind a either of those values to a `bool`, which accepts values of `true` or `false`.

Change your radio buttons to

```
<input type="radio" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" value="true" checked />
<input type="radio" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" value="false" />
```

and ditto for the `asc` group.

However what you should be doing is having a view model with properties

```
public bool Name { get; set; }
public bool Asc { get; set; }
```

and using the strong typed `HtmlHelper` methods to correctly generate you html

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, true, new { id = "" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, false, new { id = "" })
```

although a property named `Name` should probably be a `string` or `enum` rather than a `bool`.